# Nginx HTTPS SSL redirection doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-config

I've tired to configure an `Nginx` server with SSL but the site is not open but with `https://` it's open normally.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    root /var/www/mysite.in/site;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name www.mysite.com;

    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/main_private.key;
}
```

The SSL was generated in GoDaddy, I've found lots of solutions, but so far none of them are working.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you list some of the solutions you've tried that haven't worked?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two servers(http and https) in your config and create redirect from http to https:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name www.mysite.com;   

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    root /var/www/mysite.in/site;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/main_private.key;
}
```